# prompt using ASP

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm using below prompt command in ASP Classic code, box prompts up exactly but I'm not able to catch the value entered. Here I'm using flname as variable to catch the entered value. Please help. - Thanks

```
Response.write("<script type=""text/javascript"">flname=prompt(""Please enter your full name : "");</script>")
```

Comment: You're emitting code (javascript) to display the box, but the script doesn't do anything with the return value. Remember that your `Response.Write` is executing on the server. By the time that script executes on the client browser, the server-side script (your ASP code) has completed. (Also, `flname`? were the "i" and "e" taking up too much space?)

Comment: @edave I think it's short for full name

Comment: Why are you using such an old deprecated method of web development such as ASP Classic? There is absolutely no reason you should be using it when there are so many modern alternatives that will give you a vastly better experience developing even the simplest of web apps.

Comment: @AdrianBrand Agreed, but there are still quite a few large legacy ASP apps out in the wild that need to be maintained and updated. At my last web gig circa 2014, we had a 750k line classic ASP app. Reimplementing it wasn't an option.

Comment: I realise that, but this guy is asking day one noob questions. these are not the sort of questions you ask if you are taking a job supporting a legacy app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script tag stores the value to the window object of the HTML page, if you want to get it in ASP you have to read the "flname" property from window, or evaluate the global variable of it, or send an Ajax request from the browser to the server after the prompt, and read it on the next server request

Comment: Can you please provide an example?

Comment: I changed the logic. Thanks